# "Error in the program" Can anybody clear this error..? (LINUX FRAMEBUFFER PROGRAM)

Tags: c++, c, framebuffer

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
int fbfd = 0;
struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
long int screensize = 0;
char fbp = 0;
int x = 0, y = 0;
long int location = 0;

// Open the file for reading and writing
fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
if (!fbfd) {
printf("Error: cannot open framebuffer device.\n");
exit(1);
}
printf("The framebuffer device was opened successfully.\n");

// Get fixed screen information
if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo)) {
printf("Error reading fixed information.\n");
exit(2);
}

// Get variable screen information
if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo)) {
printf("Error reading variable information.\n");
exit(3);
}

// Figure out the size of the screen in bytes
screensize = vinfo.xres * vinfo.yres * vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;

// Map the device to memory
fbp = (char *)mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);
if ((int)fbp == -1) {
printf("Error: failed to map framebuffer device to memory.\n");
exit(4);
}
printf("The framebuffer device was mapped to memory successfully.\n");

for (y = 0; y < 240; y++)
{
for (x = 0; x < 320; x++)
{
x = 100; y = 100; // Where we are going to put the pixel

// Figure out where in memory to put the pixel
location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/4) + (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
*(fbp + location)= 255;


}
}
munmap(fbp, screensize);
close(fbfd);
return 0;
}


ERROR:in line number 57
getting error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *' (have ‘long int')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char fbp = 0;
```

should have been

```
char *fbp;
```